# The extent in UTM and the projection in lat lon

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal, map-projections, proj

I have a raster with 4 layers and I want to convert the extent into lon/lat, in order  to  make the  extract, but  the  points and the  raster projection or extent doesn't match. Can you please help me ?

```
pp.an
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 530, 748, 396440, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 133000, 881000, 225000, 755000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      :       X01,       X02,       X03,       X04 
min values :  13.12333,  12.16333,  16.02000,  13.00667 
max values :  75.00333,  65.92000,  88.52333, 100.46333 
           : 01, 02, 03, 04 
pshp
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 5 
extent      : 27.25892, 27.38349, 44.43456, 44.55279  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

```
pshp<- data.frame(Y =  c(44.548684, 44.533389, 44.537298, 44.4345597, 44.552794), X = c(27.258922,27.282476,27.347930,27.331980,27.383491))
coordinates(pshp) <- ~X+Y
proj4string(pshp)<- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
pshp1 <- spTransform(pshp,projection(p.p))

crs(pshp) <-"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
projectRaster(pp.an, crs = projection(pshp))
ex <- extract(pp.an, pshp1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To extract values for points from a raster with a different crs you should transform your points, not the raster (to avoid loss of precision).
2. you show that the crs of `pp.an` is set to `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84`. That is clearly wrong given that you say it is UTM and the extent of `133000, 881000, 225000, 755000`

So first you need to set the correct crs

```
crs(pp.an) <- "+proj=utm +zone=??? +datum=WGS84"
```

Then transform the points

```
pshp1 <- spTransform(pshp, projection(pp.an))
```

And then use `extract`

```
e <- extract(pp.an, pshp1)
```